# Preferred way of loading a specific entity revision

Tags: entities

In drupal 7 you can do this to load an entity revision using

[entity_load](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/entity_load/7)($entity_type, $ids = FALSE, $conditions = array(), $reset = FALSE)

like this:

```
$old_revision = entity_load('node', array(), array('vid' => 123));
```

However now $conditions is being deprecated.
Pretty much wherever you go you see people saying that you should use [EntityFieldQuery](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7) instead of conditions, however that doesn't help in this case.
You can use [age()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/property/EntityFieldQuery%3a%3aage/7) to query revisions using EntityFieldQuery however it doesn't give you fully loaded node results so you then still have to load the entity and how do you load that revision of that entity without the conditions.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Currently the preferred way is to get the storage instance ([EntityStorageInterface](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!EntityStorageInterface.php/interface/EntityStorageInterface/8.2.x)) for the entity type from the [EntityTypeManager](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!EntityTypeManager.php/class/EntityTypeManager/8.2.x) and then use its [loadRevision()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!EntityStorageInterface.php/function/EntityStorageInterface%3A%3AloadRevision/8.2.x) function. For example, you could do this for a node:

```
$node_revision = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('node')
  ->loadRevision($node_revision_id);
```

Previously to this you would get the storage instance from the [EntityManager](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!EntityManager.php/class/EntityManager/8.2.x) like this:

```
$node_revision = \Drupal::entityManager()
  ->getStorage('node')
  ->loadRevision($node_revision_id);
```

This still currently works however it has been deprecated in favour of the first method. The change record relating to this is at https://www.drupal.org/node/2549139

The old way, which still currently works in Drupal 8 but is also deprecated, is the function [entity_revision_load()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!entity.inc/function/entity_revision_load/8), which is also available in drupal 7 via [entity_revision_load()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!entity.module/function/entity_revision_load/7) in the [Entity API](https://drupal.org/project/entity) module.

This function replaces the use of conditions to load old entity revisions.
You can see the history of this change in the Drupal core issue about [Remove deprecated $conditions support from entity controller](https://drupal.org/node/1184272).

The way you would use this function as per the original question is:

```
$old_revision = entity_revision_load('node', 123);
```

Comment: Yes, this is the way to do it. There's also loadRevision() on the entity storage interface (this is a wrapper for that).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have now updated the answer with the current preferred method using the EntityTypeManager.

Comment: But how do you get the revision id in the first place? e.g. Let's say i have only an entity id, and i want to fetch the 10 latest revisions for it. What's the prefered way to build the revision query?

Comment: Answered my own question: entityStorageInterface::getQuery will create the query that i need. ::allRevisions() will cause the query to query both the base table and entity tables. Conditions apply as expected, and return value is an array indexed by vid.